# Perl IO::Socket::SSL persistent TCP connection

Tags: android, perl, ssl

I am writing a perl script for communicating with android GCM CCS. My script looks like the below:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $client = IO::Socket::SSL->new('gcm.googleapis.com:5236')
    or die "error=$!, ssl_error=$SSL_ERROR";

print $client '<stream:stream to="gcm.googleapis.com" version="1.0"
#xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"/>';
print <$client>;
print $client '<auth mechanism="PLAIN"
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">MTI2MjAwMzQ3OTMzQHByb2plY3RzLmdjbS5hb
mFTeUIzcmNaTmtmbnFLZEZiOW1oekNCaVlwT1JEQTJKV1d0dw==</auth>';

if(!<$client>){
    print "Auth error\n";
} else {
    print <$client>;
}
```

After writing the first request on the socket I get response as expected from google server. And I cant print the server response using print 
But, I dont get any response after writing the second request. It seems like the connection gets closed after the first request and response or something. How do I send multiple request through open TLS connection and receive server responses ?

**Update**

I get the below if I turn on debugging

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1464: new ctx 145780168
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:332: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:334: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:347: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:390: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:445: ssl handshake done
  write_all VM at entry=vm_unknown
  written so far 124:124 bytes (VM=vm_unknown)
  write_all VM at entry=vm_unknown
  written so far 188:188 bytes (VM=vm_unknown)
  got 147:0 bytes (VM=vm_unknown).
  got 197:147 bytes (VM=vm_unknown).
  got 0:344 bytes (VM=vm_unknown).
  got 0:0 bytes (VM=vm_unknown).
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1201: SSL read errorerror:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

<stream:stream from="gcm.googleapis.com" id="626DAFBE58C7FD0D" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>Auth error
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1500: free ctx 145780168 open=145780168
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1508: OK free ctx 145780168
```

Answer (score 3):

> DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1201: SSL read errorerror:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

The server closed the connection. There is nothing you can do to keep the connection open and send more if the server decides to close the connection. The close might be related to the Auth error you received.

Also:

> ```
> print <$client>;
> ```

You are calling the `<>` operator in list context. This means it will try to read *all* lines from the socket. Since *all* lines is only finished once the server has closed the connection (this is how TCP works and has nothing to do with TLS), you effectively wait here until the server closes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The Auth error is coming from the if block not from the server. How can I read partially? As you can see im trying to establish a persistence both way communication with the server (over TLS) any idea how I may do it? Here is an example with python that connects with Google CCS server and for this one Google doesnt close the connection. So I must be doing something wrong in client side, 
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#python

Comment: The Auth error comes from the if block because the server closed the connection. And the server closed the connection because you've waited within the `print <$client>` until the server closed (list context). For partial reads you use better sysread. And then you have to find out when the message ends, i.e. do the XML parsing stuff etc. Again, this has nothing to do with TLS and is the same with normal TCP connections.